# Passing a temp pointer to a temp pointer to an object

Tags: c++, pointers, visual-studio-2012, parameter-passing

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tchar.h>

void output(int *param)
{
    std::cout << "Value: " << *param << std::endl;
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int i = 34;

    output(&i);

    return 0;
}
```

obviously writes "Value: 34" to the console.

But if I make the following changes

```
...
void output(int **param)
{
    std::cout << "Value: " << **param << std::endl;
}
...
    output(&(&i));
...
```

I get a compile error "'&' requires l-value".

By the way, I even tried to make the following change:

```
output(&34);
```

Indeed this feels wrong ... somehow.

My question is: **Why** is this not allowed to use & at an r-value? Is there some reason on assembler level?

Comment: `&i` is a temporary object. You are not able to get its address.

Comment: @Melebius OK, so I cannot get the address. But as it *has* an address why am I not able to get it? Why? Is it because on a deeper level (assembler maybe) we are talking about a register instead of a "normal" address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to get a reference to a r-value and that is basically not defined, since it is always a temporary value and actually never has an address on the stack/heap. That is why C++11 introduced r-value references, but that is a totally different subject to your question.

To get your code to compile your need to do the following:

```
int   i = 34;
int* pi = &i;

output(&ip);
```

By "grounding" your reference in `pi`, you give the compiler a real address on the stack that can be given to `output`.

Comment: "it is always a temporary value and actually never has an address on the stack/heap" What does that mean? Where is this address if not at the stack or heap and why am I not allowed to store it? Is there some reason that can only be understood on assembler level?

Comment: Basically the value just exists as a CPU register and may never be on the stack.

Comment: Do you know if this applies to l-values in general? Is it compiler or processor dependent? And would you be so kind to add your last comment to the answer because that is what I was searching for.

Comment: The actual implementation of the l-value varies widely from compiler to compiler, platform to platform and case to case. But the actual implementation is irrelevant, since any standard conforming compiler will not let you take a reference to the l-value. Consider the l-value as being ephemeral.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to get the address of an address, and an address is not an l-value. *(You can very roughly think about l-values as values that can stand on the left side of an operation. Variables, and "named values" are l-values, for example)*

Store the first address somewhere.

```
int number = 4;
int* firstAddress = &number;
int** secondAddress = &firstAddress;

output(secondAddress);
```